# Testing function submit() in Component + Service, using Angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I need to test function submit. I have this code:

```
onAddProd() {
    this.areWeWaiting = true;
    let newProd= new Product(
      this.addProdForm.value
    );
    this.ws.createProduct(newProd).subscribe( //createProduct is function service
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        } else {
          this.areWeWaiting = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.areWeWaiting = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

I need basically testing. 
- If result is true should be navigate ti `/home`

Can you suggest me any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

First rthings first: there is much going on in your function. It whould be a good idea to test all the services independently.

Especially the **routing** to `/home` is managed by the `Route` module and must be tested in a separate file. More details on [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component).

A key point to testing your function is to be able to **mock** all services that are called. You usually have to declare those mocks before the `describe` function

```
let wsMock
let routerMock

describe('MyComponentUnderTest', () => {
  let component: MyComponentUnderTest
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponentUnderTest>
  ...
})
```

Next, you have to initiate the mocks and override the values it shall return during the test:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  wsMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('ws', ['createProduct'])
  wsMock.createProduct.and.returnValue(of(SOME_VALUE_THAT_YOU_HAVE_TO_SET))

  routerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate'])
}))
```

Last but not least, your `beforeEach` function is concluded by the configuration of the testing module, in which you have to inject your mocked services:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ws, useValue: wsMock},
    {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock}
  ]
})
.compileComponents()
```

That's it for the boiler plate. Let's move on to the test:

```
it('should create a product', () => {
  component.onAddProd()
  expect(component.areWeWaiting).toBeTruthy()
})
```

You may visit [Angular web site](https://angular.io/guide/testing) for more details about component testing.

Comment: Yes, I testing my component, for example forms. I need to test only this function. Which are best way to test this submit function?

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I explained to you: test all services / components individually, then create mocks for all services called by this function, then test your function. Testing the truthyness or falsyness of `areWeWaiting` seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

In beforeEach function declare

```
Providers: [
....
{ provide: Router, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj("router", ["navigate"]) }
]
const injector = getTestBed();
router = injector.get(Router);
```

and in the function,

```
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/home"]);
```